# Hibernate: save a new parent with the children inside without editing auto-generated bean and xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have this bean that is auto-generated from DB:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "richiesta", catalog = "gestione_utenza")
public class Richiesta implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idRichiesta;
    private MessaggiErrore messaggiErrore;
    private Stato stato;
    private Date dataInserimento;
    private Date dataElaborazione;
    private String nota;
    private String usernameAssegnato;
    private String utenteAutorizzante;
    private String urlattivazione;
    private Anagrafica anagrafica;
    private Set<RichiestaApplicazione> richiestaApplicaziones = new HashSet<RichiestaApplicazione>(
            0);

    public Richiesta() {
    }

    public Richiesta(Stato stato, Date dataInserimento) {
        this.stato = stato;
        this.dataInserimento = dataInserimento;
    }

    public Richiesta(MessaggiErrore messaggiErrore, Stato stato,
            Date dataInserimento, Date dataElaborazione, String nota,
            String usernameAssegnato, String utenteAutorizzante,
            String urlattivazione, Anagrafica anagrafica,
            Set<RichiestaApplicazione> richiestaApplicaziones) {
        this.messaggiErrore = messaggiErrore;
        this.stato = stato;
        this.dataInserimento = dataInserimento;
        this.dataElaborazione = dataElaborazione;
        this.nota = nota;
        this.usernameAssegnato = usernameAssegnato;
        this.utenteAutorizzante = utenteAutorizzante;
        this.urlattivazione = urlattivazione;
        this.anagrafica = anagrafica;
        this.richiestaApplicaziones = richiestaApplicaziones;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idRichiesta", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIdRichiesta() {
        return this.idRichiesta;
    }

    public void setIdRichiesta(Integer idRichiesta) {
        this.idRichiesta = idRichiesta;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codiceErrore")
    public MessaggiErrore getMessaggiErrore() {
        return this.messaggiErrore;
    }

    public void setMessaggiErrore(MessaggiErrore messaggiErrore) {
        this.messaggiErrore = messaggiErrore;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stato", nullable = false)
    public Stato getStato() {
        return this.stato;
    }

    public void setStato(Stato stato) {
        this.stato = stato;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dataInserimento", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getDataInserimento() {
        return this.dataInserimento;
    }

    public void setDataInserimento(Date dataInserimento) {
        this.dataInserimento = dataInserimento;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dataElaborazione", length = 19)
    public Date getDataElaborazione() {
        return this.dataElaborazione;
    }

    public void setDataElaborazione(Date dataElaborazione) {
        this.dataElaborazione = dataElaborazione;
    }

    @Column(name = "nota", length = 256)
    public String getNota() {
        return this.nota;
    }

    public void setNota(String nota) {
        this.nota = nota;
    }

    @Column(name = "usernameAssegnato", length = 20)
    public String getUsernameAssegnato() {
        return this.usernameAssegnato;
    }

    public void setUsernameAssegnato(String usernameAssegnato) {
        this.usernameAssegnato = usernameAssegnato;
    }

    @Column(name = "utenteAutorizzante", length = 20)
    public String getUtenteAutorizzante() {
        return this.utenteAutorizzante;
    }

    public void setUtenteAutorizzante(String utenteAutorizzante) {
        this.utenteAutorizzante = utenteAutorizzante;
    }

    @Column(name = "URLattivazione", length = 80)
    public String getUrlattivazione() {
        return this.urlattivazione;
    }

    public void setUrlattivazione(String urlattivazione) {
        this.urlattivazione = urlattivazione;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "richiesta")
    public Anagrafica getAnagrafica() {
        return this.anagrafica;
    }

    public void setAnagrafica(Anagrafica anagrafica) {
        this.anagrafica = anagrafica;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "richiesta")
    public Set<RichiestaApplicazione> getRichiestaApplicaziones() {
        return this.richiestaApplicaziones;
    }

    public void setRichiestaApplicaziones(
            Set<RichiestaApplicazione> richiestaApplicaziones) {
        this.richiestaApplicaziones = richiestaApplicaziones;
    }

}
```

I want to add a new Richiesta, with his childs, but with the code that I wrote I'm able to add only a new row in the table Richiesta:

```
Richiesta ric = new Richiesta();
Stato st = new Stato();
st.setIdStato(1);
ric.setStato(st);
ric.setDataInserimento(new Date());

Integer[] appId = getApplicazioniSelezionateDefault();
for (int k=0; k<appId.length; k++)
{
    Applicazione ap = new Applicazione();
    ap.setIdApplicazione(appId[k]);
    ric.getRichiestaApplicaziones().add( new RichiestaApplicazione( ap, ric));
}

Ufficio uf = new Ufficio();
uf.setIdufficio(this.getUfficioVDR());
Qualifica qu = new Qualifica();
qu.setIdQualifica( CommonUtil.getIndexInteger(getQualificaSelezionataVDR()) );
ric.setAnagrafica(new Anagrafica(uf, qu, ric, getCognomeVDR(), getNomeVDR(), getDataNascitaVDR(), getTelefonoVDR(), getEmailVDR(), getIpVDR()));

Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(ric);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

I would like to have a new row in the table Anagrafica, and "N" news rows in the table RichiestaApplicazione.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "anagrafica", catalog = "gestione_utenza")
public class Anagrafica implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idRichiesta;
    private Ufficio ufficio;
    private Qualifica qualifica;
    private Richiesta richiesta;
    private String cognome;
    private String nome;
    private Date dataNascita;
    private String telefono;
    private String email;
    private String ip;

    [...]

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "richiesta"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "idRichiesta", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIdRichiesta() {
        return this.idRichiesta;
    }

    [...]
}
```

I read to add the CASCADE attribute to the xml/annotation, is it possible to make it without editing annotation/xml? For example adding something in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To become persistent, a new entity instance must be added to the persistent context with `session.persist(newEntity)` or `session.save(newEntity)`. You haven't called this method on anything except `ric`. So all the other created entities are still not persistent.

Comment: I've called this: session.save(ric);

Comment: That makes ric saved. But not all the other entities.

Comment: But if I put inside ric the object Anagrafica like I did, why both are not saved? ric.setAnagrafica(new Anagrafica(uf, qu, ric, getCognomeVDR(), getNomeVDR(), getDataNascitaVDR(), getTelefonoVDR(), getEmailVDR(), getIpVDR()));

Comment: Because that's not how it works, how it has been designed, and how the JPA specifications specified it. Either you add cascades which allow that, or you explicitely call `save()`.

Comment: If I want that the auto-generated bean have the "cascades" specification, do I need to set a specific reveng.xml? Right?

Comment: It's your code, not a tool's code. You'd better hand-craft it, add all the methods and annotations you find useful. You can't blindly add cascades everywhere.

Comment: Yes, but if the DB changes, maybe it's easiest  to regenerate all the bean than to change every annotations.